# Vaadin Listener Server-side vs Element-API, what are the prefered use-cases?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

To add e.g. a click listener to a button there are (to my knowledge) two ways in Vaadin:

```
1. button.addClickListener(clickEvent -> ...);
2. button.getElement().addEventListener("click", event -> ...);
```

The first uses a lot of Vaadin-Code to register a new listener, returns a Registration object and has a ClickEvent-object with many convenience functions (get click coordinates etc.)

The second registers the click event directly to the element and returns a DomListenerRegistration object (which looks confusing compared to Registration). As far as I understand, this solution is more flexible (you can use all browser events, you can choose which information you want to extract additional to "event got fired") and more sleek. Correct me if I am wrong on any point.

So what are the typical use cases for both variants? What are advantages or disadvantages of them?

In my humble opinion I would chose the convenience function (1.) whenever it has all functionality that I need, and only use the second version when I need more flexibility or when I want to get maximum performance.

Comment: my 2ct: use the API, if it's there - it usually is easier, more thought out, ... - and use the DOM interfacing, if you need the escape hatch (e.g. the component has features not mapped in the API or when you wire your own component and there really is just that one event you need). Sometimes the API is just a thing wrapper around the plumbing, but that does not have to make you scratch your head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have normal Vaadin `Button`, then you really should use this

```
button.addClickListener(clickEvent -> ...);
```

To add the click listener to the button.

Element API is low level API, and you would like to use it in the cases you are implementing custom components of your own and need to listen for client side events, especially custom events etc.